# Unit test in Django dont see correct redirect url for successfull login?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-1.11

In my Django project I create custom admin page (NOT admin from Django). I have 2 login pages. One for admin, second for other users.

Here below you can see **urls.py** file for admin. I test it and it works fine. After successful login Django redirect user to url which was **next** parameter (`/administration/dashboard/`).

I wrote **unit test** and it raise error. From error I understand that Django redirect to default url (`/accounts/profile/`). Why unit test dont use settings which I did in urls.py file (next parameter)?

How to fix this problem?

Right now I notice that problem disappear only if I use this code `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/administration/dashboard/'` in *settings.py*. I cant use it cause in the future I will use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to my other login page.

I would be grateful for any help!

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as authentication_views

urlpatterns = [
    # Administration Login
    url(r'^login/$',
        authentication_views.login,
        {
            'template_name': 'administration/login.html',
            'authentication_form': AdministrationAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context': {
                'next': reverse_lazy('administration:dashboard'),
            },
            'redirect_authenticated_user': True
        },
        name='administration_login'),
]
```

**tests.py:**

```
class AdministrationViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.credentials = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'}
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(self.credentials, is_staff=True)
        self.data = dict(
            self.credentials,
            next=reverse("administration:dashboard")
        )

    def test_administration_authorization(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.user)

        # logged_in = self.client.login(**self.credentials)
        # self.assertTrue(logged_in)

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("administration:administration_login"),
            self.data,
            follow=True
        )
        # self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(
            response,
            reverse("administration:dashboard"),
            status_code=302,
            target_status_code=200
        )
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nurzhan/CA/administration/tests.py", line 51, in test_administration_authorization
    reverse("administration:dashboard"),
  File "/srv/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 271, in assertRedirects
    % (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class AdministrationAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """
        A custom authentication form used in the administration application.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': (
            _("ERROR MESSAGE.")
        ),
    }
    required_css_class = 'required'

def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
    if not user.is_active or not user.is_staff:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
            code='invalid_login',
            params={
                'username': self.username_field.verbose_name
            }
        )
```

**login.html:**

```
<form action="{% url 'administration:administration_login' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the result when you print `reverse("administration:administration_login")`?

Comment: Result is: `/administration/login/`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I comment this line `logged_in = self.client.login(**self.credentials)` and then add `self.credentials` to my post response. Now it raise error: `AssertionError: Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)` to line `reverse("administration:dashboard")`. Check my post again for details pls.

Answer (score 0):

[Django isn't checking `next` in `extra_context`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L94) but in `GET` and `POST` params.

[`extra_context` is used to update your template context](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L129). So if you want to pass the values for variables to your template you can set those with `extra_context`.

However, you can fix your test by either [setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L104) or passing next as a POST or GET param.

```
params = dict(**self.credentials, next=reverse("home:index"))
response = self.client.post(
    url,
    params,
    follow=True
)
```

#### NOTE:

> `self.credentials` should be unpacked in the dict being applied to `self.data`.

```
self.data = dict(
    **self.credentials,
    next=reverse("administration:dashboard")
)
```

If you wanted to test without making this change, I can recommend another way to test this.

You need to render your template in a browser and fill out the login form. This way your browser client will make the `POST` request with `next` passed as a parameter.
You can get this done with a headless browser using `selenium webdriver`.

Comment: I tried your code but it steal raise the same error: `AssertionError: Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)`. I add my `forms.py` and `login.html` files. Can you check it pls?  It seems to me that problem because of them.

Comment: See my note about unpacking `self.credentials` in the `dict` assigned to self.data

Comment: I did exactly as you said but unfortunately it did help me. Steal the same error. I think problems with my custom form. Can you check it pls? Also I tried to test my form with next code: `form = AdministrationAuthenticationForm(data=self.credentials)` then `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())` but it raise error like: `AssertionError: False is not true` It mean that form is not valid. Something wrong with my form but I dont know where exactly.

Comment: I know this is old but you can use `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form.errors)` for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `follow=True` in the POST request. You are checking for a redirection but you are telling the `requests` modules to follow the redirection, so your response will be directly the page and not the `302` redirection HTTP response.

To be more explicit. You are sending a request with `requests.post(follow=True)`, that will follow the `302` redirection to the destination page and your `response` will be a HTTP 200 with the destination page. Even if the destination page is the one you want, the test assertion will fail because is looking for a HTTP 302 code in your response and you've already followed the redirection.